# Where does AWS Lifecycle manager save the snapshot it takes as backup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I configured a set of Lifecycle manager Policies to back-up my EC2 instances last week, but I cannot find any relevant snapshots in the EBS snapshots section. Can someone please advise if I should look for the snapshots somewhere else, or if I should review any specific parameters that regard the policy, or if even I should use another method?

Thank you.

[Schedule details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6WpI.png)

Answer (score 2):

Lifecycle manager will create the backup as a regular EBS snapshot, EBS snapshots are stored in S3 however you do not have access to the snapshot other than through the console/API.

Based on your configuration it will only apply to a tag of `Name` with the value of `Graylog v3.3.2`. This will happen once a week at 12:30PM UTC on a Monday.

If the snapshots are not being generated check the following:

- Do the target instances have this name and value assigned to them?
- Does the execution IAM role have permissions to perform this action? If it has the [default permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/snapshot-lifecycle.html#dlm-permissions) then it will be fine to run.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer and apologies for this issue I'm kind of new to AWS and I managed to solve it.
The issue was simply in the filter applied to the snapshots tab I wasn't seeing the full name. bottom line the policy was working fine after all.